# how to work with the loader when the screen is rotated

Tags: java, android

I try to use Loaders instead AsyncTask.I can not figure out how to correctly organize the conservation status when the screen is rotated. I receive information from Json and trying create list.

```
public class FragmentWeatherTestApplication extends Fragment
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<WeatherItem>> {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this).forceLoad();
}

 ...

@Override
public Loader<List<WeatherItem>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateLoader");
    return new FetchWeatherLoader(getActivity());
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<WeatherItem>> loader, List<WeatherItem> data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onLoadFinished");
    mItems = data;
    setupAdapter();
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<WeatherItem>> loader) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onLoaderReset");
}

   .... 


  private static class FetchWeatherLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<WeatherItem>>{

    public FetchWeatherLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public List<WeatherItem> loadInBackground() {
        return new OpenWeatherFetch().fetchItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: i suggest looking at this blog http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html.

Comment: what do you mean by conversation status ?

Comment: Loader loading data when sceen is rotate, but i want that this is done only when the application starts

Comment: getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this).forceLoad(); use this where u start application

Comment: brykneval, I did it, but the loader loads data from Json again, how to avoid it?